# Mapping Arguments from URL Segments

Tags: php, url-routing

URL: example.com/catalog/product/sort/pd.name/order/desc

I'm building out some custom routing. When exploding this url string I get an array that looks like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => catalog
    [1] => product
    [2] => sort
    [3] => pd.name
    [4] => order
    [5] => desc
)
```

Key 0 and 1 is my controller. If my array was an odd number, then key 2 would be the method. Everything else needs to be set into my request service like so:

```
Request::set('sort', 'pd.name');
Request::set('order', 'desc');
```

I'm sure there must be a simple, elegant way to do this, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: which framework is this ?

Comment: My own, but I have quite a few composer packages installed, most notably Lumen for my API, but the main app doesn't use Lumen/Laravel style routing so that's out.

Comment: i have some problem understanding what your need is, if you can edit your question and explain more about what you want, i would be able to help

Comment: I'm not sure how I can edit it to make more sense. Keys 2-5 should be key/value pairs. If the url was a query string it would look like so: `example.com/index.php?route=catalog/product&sort=pd.name&order=desc`. What I need is something similar to the `parse_str` method but that will work on an array instead of a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about..

```
$controller = array_pop($array);
$controller2 = array_pop($array);

for($i=0;$i<=count($array),$i+2){

    Request::set($array[$i],$array[$i+1]);

}
```

Comment: I ended up using a modified version of this I found in the new Laravel code base. Thanks.